# Extending Spring Data Neo4j - handling scala types and other things

Tags: spring, scala, spring-data-neo4j

I am using `SDN` from scala language and there is a bit of a problem because `SDN` for example, does not know how to handle `Options`. I stumbled today on this little project on GitHub: https://github.com/glerchundi/spring-data-neo4j-scala-support.

Unfortunately it is not compatible with API in `3.X` branches of `SDN`. I was wondering if there is any manual/blog-post/anything that would help me in extending `SDN` to achieve few things:

1. generic `Option` handling
2. some way to handle `Scala` collections, like `Set` so they would be mapped as their `Java` counterparts

Basically some tutorial/project that would show what classes I need to extend to get some custom mapping going on.

Also, in this project `Spring` was configured using `Java` class. I am wondering if it is possible to register some custom components in `SDN` infrastructure using xml based configuration? (apart from simple `Converters`).

I know about converters but they only allow you to map one field to other, and even this won't work if I try mapping `Set` to `java.util.Set`.

EDIT: 
My bad, I noticed that classes in this sample project are using some classes that are only accessible from `SDN` packages. When I created proper package structure (meaning I did not change anything) I can now save `Options` for example.

But still I am wondering if there is some cleaner way and also if it is possible to do something like this using xml configuration

EDIT: If anyone is interested I forked the mentioned project and done some bugfixes. When I will have some time I will try to add support of `@RelatedTo` for `Scala` collections (currently you can only have `Scala` collections for graph properties).

Comment: I'd be very interested in seeing a dependable Scala extensions to SDN. +1 for @RelatedTo Scala collections!

Comment: Hey, currently I am not doing anything with `@RelatedTo` implementation unfortunately because lack of time. For now I am using java collections + java converters available in Scala standard library: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters$